# Javascript get height IE wrong values

Tags: javascript, html

I have strange problem in my application that I can't solve. In my code I do something like this:

```
$tds.each(function(index) {
    parentHeightArray.push($(this).parent().outerHeight());
});
```

`$tds` is simply a jquery object containing all `<div>` tags that are in table cell.

In FF it returns correct values, but in IE they are too low. When I execute the same code in `setTimeout` function I get good values what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: Is there some content that is still loading when that code runs?

Comment: I agree with @user1689607.  There must be content that is still loading.  if it's just the html of the page, try placing your script tags at the bottom of the document just before the body closing tag.  If it has to do with jquery, use the `$(docuemnt).ready(function(){})` syntax

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to with either the DOM not fully constructed **or** the content not fully loaded.

Try putting your JavaScript inside of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

**or** inside of:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // your code
});
```

Also make sure that you have a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) that doesn't trigger the [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). See: [Triggering different rendering modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes) on Wikipedia.